# How to make a form insert field value into SQL in Microsoft Access without it being a parameter query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

For a friends list in a database, I have two tables: people and friends. I have a form with a combo box that lists the names of the people in the people table. Under the list I have a button with that links to this SQL code:

```
SELECT People.FirstName, People.Email, People.Phone
FROM People INNER JOIN Friend ON People.ID = Friend.FriendWithPersonID
WHERE Friend.PersonID=[Forms]![People]![Combo 4].value;
```

When I click the button, a "Enter Parameter Value" box pops up, but I don't want it to pop up. I want it to take the ID from the person I selected in the combo box to run the query. I've tried taking the .value off, but it doesn't work right then.

The form name is people, and the combo box name is Combo 4.

I mean it does exactly what I want when I enter a value into the parameter box, but I don't want users to have to be figuring out what the ID of each person is.

How can I fix this?

Also, if you can tell me how to do this in SQL, and not another programming language because I only know SQL at the moment.

Comment: When that form is open, how does Access respond to this statement in the Immediate window? `Debug.Print [Forms]![People]![Combo 4].value`  If you're not familiar with the Immediate window, you can use Ctrl+g to go there.  Then paste in that statement and press Enter.

Comment: It says, "Runtime error "2465" Microsoft Access can't find the field combo 4 referred to in your expression

Comment: OK, what happens if you remove the space from the combo name? `Debug.Print [Forms]![People]![Combo4].value`

Comment: I found out what I did wrong. There wasn't supposed to be a space between combo and 4. Thanks! Great debugging trick!